# XML data binding wizard alternative

Tags: xml, delphi, xsd

The Delphi data binding wizard seem to have problems with complex XSD files.
Whenever several XSD files reference each other (using the @include keyword i believe), the prefixing of namespaces go out the window.
This makes it impossible to use the Delphi XML data binding wizard with large and complex schemas. In my case, the [standard message structures](http://www.kith.no/templates/kith_WebPage____1018.aspx) used by the Norwegian government.

Are there any alternative xml data binding wizards on the marked?
At the moment i have to generate the XML by code which is less than desireable. The whole point of using the automated wizard is to save time and being able to adapt to changes in standards more quickly.

See the following article for a more in-depth presentation of the problem:
[Delphi XML Databinding pains](http://jonlennartaasenden.wordpress.com/2013/09/17/delphi-xml-data-binding-pains/)

Comment: Why doesn't Embarcadero open-source it?

Answer (score 1):

Pre-processing the xsd-files to include the includes might be a more effective way to go than searching for another data binder. Or, if your work process allows for it, generate binding from the xsd-conformant xml rather than from the xsd.